# Putting raster file with big extention in shapefile

Tags: raster, arcmap

**Hello, 
I have a raster file with huge extention values:**

Top 2862682.68853

Left -8067545.46588

Right 17050954.5341

Bottom -2862317.31147

Spatial reference WGS_1984_Mollweide

Liniar Unit Meter 1.00000

Angular Unit Degree (0.017453292519943299)

Datum D_WGS_1984

**And I want to fit it in the same projection as a shapefile**

Geometry Type:  Polygon

Projected Coordinate System:    WGS_1984_World_Mercator

Projection: Mercator

False_Easting:  0.00000000

False_Northing: 0.00000000

Central_Meridian:   0.00000000

Standard_Parallel_1:    0.00000000

Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_WGS_1984

Datum:  D_WGS_1984

Prime Meridian:     Greenwich

Angular Unit:   Degree

**I have been trying to batch in the same projection but nothing really worked. 
Do you know how can I do that?**

Comment: have you the epsg codes for the mollweide projection and the shapefile? I'd say the mollweide could be 53009 or 54009

Comment: I'd do exactly the opposite: reproject the shape file and work any spatial analysis using the raster projection.